# Using TVP table valued parameter, what are some of the steps to be caucious about?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I am using Table Valued Parameter with ADO.NET and my stored procedure is not working properly. I have 2 other that work fine. I compared the code the order of table etc and they ALL seem to be OK.

The data gets passed from my code to stored procedure with no error it does not simply insert. I wonder if there is something I don't know I am missing ... I am totally lost.. spent a whole lot of time trying to figure but can't.

Everything seems to be fine no error nothing yet it is not working.

Here is the type:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[NameTableType] AS TABLE(
[ID] [int] NULL,
[MYID] [int] NULL,
[Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    )
    GO
```

and this is my table

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert]
(
@TVP as NameTableType readonly
)                                      
AS
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
  BEGIN TRY
      INSERT INTO [dbo].[MYTABLE]
      ([ID],[MYID],[NAME])
      SELECT [ID],[MYID],[NAME]
       from @TVP
      COMMIT TRANSACTION
  END TRY

  BEGIN CATCH
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
  END CATCH
```

Is there something I should be cautious in my database and what is it? Is there a way to return an error if the procedure fails?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)?  If so, try running the stored procedure there.  If it runs in SSMS then you have a problem with your ADO.Net code, which is the most likely source of your problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? The data isn't ending up in your table? Please check to make sure that you are connecting to the same copy of the database. Does your connection string include a parameter like `AttachDbFileName`?

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with SSMS tool but I can get it can you tell me where I could run this if I get that tool?

Comment: It does not insert, my database works with other 2 insert I have not this one. No error in my VS.

Comment: So did you try doing anything useful in the `CATCH` block, like raising the error?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio is available for download from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062

Comment: Can you remove MVC tags ?

Comment: Actually SP1 is the better SSMS Express download, since it is free and fully functional, unlike RTM and previous versions. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579

Comment: Hopefully you didn't really name a proc INSERT! Avoid the use of reserved words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of just catching and discarding the error, try:

```
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    DECLARE @msg NVARCHAR(MAX) = ERROR_MESSAGE();
    RAISERROR(@msg, 11, 1);
    RETURN;
END CATCH
```

Right now you're basically saying "if there's an error, just ignore it."

Answer (score 1):

1. Check In case of any trigger causing the issue.
2. Sql Profiler can be useful in this situation